# BGP peer not advertising routes

Tags: bgp

In the topology, I have all internal Peers (Site A,B,C) in AS 65002. these peers are connected through the transit ATT router (using AS number 1500 as in topology). The problem is, site C can ping only to the advertised networks from site A (10.2.254.9) and site B(10.11.254.9). It doesn't see the  network segment between site A and site B i.e. the 10.10.254.x network even thou these are all being advertised. However, the ATT router could see it with no issues.

What am I missing?[image]

Comment: Could you include the BGP configs of all three routers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ATT router will advertise the route to router C, but the path will contain AS 65002 (from A).
C will see that as a routing loop (since its AS is also 65002) and discard the route.

If you can, change the AS number of C to something else.

Comment: if I wanted to have the same AS number 65002 can you suggest a way to do it?

Comment: I can think of ways to jury-rig a way to do it, but I wouldn't recommend any of them.  The best way is to use a different AS.

Comment: Great!  You can mark the question answered if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is use L3vpn via bgp option A technique at ATT router with igp protocols at both ends and redistribute into 
address-family ipv4 vrf Cust_A under  bgp 1500. it works properlyand it overcome AS loop prevention feature.
Also you can use lable swaping per route like as seemless vpn technique